# Errors after reducing layers of a docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am getting multiple errors when I reduce layer in the following image file.

**configure: error: in `/root/xdebug': configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH See` config.log' for more details**

Following Original file is not giving me any errors. it's only when I make the changes to the file. I think it has something to do with permissions and the way I'm adding steps.

```
FROM amazonlinux

ARG DOCKER_TYPE
ENV DOCKER_TYPE=$DOCKER_TYPE
ARG UID

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install sudo -y
RUN sudo yum install git -y
RUN sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2 -y
RUN sudo yum install php-mbstring -y
RUN sudo yum install php-openssl -y
RUN sudo yum install php-pdo_mysql -y
RUN sudo yum install php-simplexml -y
RUN sudo yum install php-soap -y
RUN sudo yum install php-spl -y
RUN sudo yum install php-xsl -y
RUN sudo yum install php-zip -y
RUN sudo yum install php-libxml -y
RUN sudo yum install php-intl -y
RUN sudo yum install php-iconv -y
RUN sudo yum install php-hash -y
RUN sudo yum install php-gd -y
RUN sudo yum install php-dom -y
RUN sudo yum install php-curl -y
RUN sudo yum install php-ctype -y 
RUN sudo yum install php-bcmath -y
RUN sudo yum install php-devel -y
RUN sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools" -y

# Xdebug
RUN cd /root/; git clone https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git; cd /root/xdebug/; ./rebuild.sh
```

Updated version

```
FROM amazonlinux

ARG DOCKER_TYPE
ENV DOCKER_TYPE=$DOCKER_TYPE
ARG UID

    RUN yum update -y
    RUN yum install sudo -y && sudo yum install -y \
        git \
        amazon-linux-extras install php7.2 \
        php-mbstring \
        php-openssl \
        php-pdo_mysql \
        php-simplexml \
        php-soap \
        php-spl \
        php-xsl \
        php-zip \
        php-libxml \
        php-intl \
        php-iconv \
        php-hash \
        php-gd \
        php-dom \
        php-curl \
        php-ctype \
        php-bcmath \
        php-devel \
        groupinstall "Development tools"
    
# Xdebug
  RUN cd /root/; git clone https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git; cd /root/xdebug/; ./rebuild.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the line

```
RUN sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
```

with an argument to `yum install`.
That's apparently something different.

You can probably fix it by adding `&&` after `git` and starting a new `sudo yum install` for the following packages.

Indentation which clearly shows where a new command is started and where you just add more arguments to a command would help readability a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated dockerfile should look something like this:

```
FROM amazonlinux

ARG DOCKER_TYPE
ENV DOCKER_TYPE=$DOCKER_TYPE
ARG UID

RUN yum update -y                                   && \
    yum install sudo -y                             && \
    sudo yum install git -y                         && \
    sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2 -y      && \
    sudo yum install php-mbstring -y                && \
    sudo yum install php-openssl -y                 && \
    sudo yum install php-pdo_mysql -y               && \
    sudo yum install php-simplexml -y               && \
    sudo yum install php-soap -y                    && \
    sudo yum install php-spl -y                     && \
    sudo yum install php-xsl -y                     && \
    sudo yum install php-zip -y                     && \
    sudo yum install php-libxml -y                  && \
    sudo yum install php-intl -y                    && \
    sudo yum install php-iconv -y                   && \
    sudo yum install php-hash -y                    && \
    sudo yum install php-gd -y                      && \
    sudo yum install php-dom -y                     && \
    sudo yum install php-curl -y                    && \
    sudo yum install php-ctype -y                   && \
    sudo yum install php-bcmath -y                  && \
    sudo yum install php-devel -y                   && \
    sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools" -y    && \
    sudo yum clean all

# Xdebug
RUN cd /root/; git clone https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git; cd /root/xdebug/; ./rebuild.sh
```

To change multiple "RUN" instructions you need to run them with && between them. The "\" character marks that the instruction continues in the next line.
I've also added

> yum clean all

at the end of this single RUN instruction to keep your image layers smaller.